# JavaFX buttons with same size

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have these buttons with different size:

[Image](http://postimg.org/image/60wp1a06l/)

How I can make all buttons with same with size?

Answer (score 13):

It depends on layout where the button is located. For example, if you add all the buttons into GridPane or BorderPane, you have to specify each button width to correspond to certain variable. In the following example I wrap all buttons inside VBox, set VBox preference width and tie up all buttons minimum width to it:

```
VBox vBox = new VBox();
vBox.setPrefWidth(100);

Button btn1 = new Button("Short");
Button btn2 = new Button("Super Long Button");

btn1.setMinWidth(vBox.getPrefWidth());
btn2.setMinWidth(vBox.getPrefWidth());

vBox.getChildren().addAll(btn1, btn2);
```

It is also worth to mention that there are two ways to specify the button size. You can do it in the java code or specify it in javafx .fxml file. The above method is an example for java code implementation.

---

You can also unclamp a button's maximum dimensions so it will grow to fill the available space (unlike most nodes, by default a button node has it's max size clamped to it's preferred size so it doesn't usually grow to fill available space).  An Oracle tutorial on [Tips for Sizing and Aligning Nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm#JFXLY133) explains this in more detail.

```
VBox vBox = new VBox();

Button btn1 = new Button("Short");
Button btn2 = new Button("Super Long Button");

btn1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
btn2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

vBox.getChildren().addAll(btn1, btn2);
```

Comment: There are a couple more variations: Set a minimum width on each of the buttons to the same value using Java code. Set a minimum button width in the CSS style sheet for the scene. I was writing my own answer but as it was similar to yours I thought I'd just add a comment.

Comment: Yup, there a lot more properties that can be specify but the button size usually wrap around the text if you do not specify any size properties to it. My answer shows the simplest way to make the width same with few lines.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for pointing my mistake. I've fixed the answer. It might not solve text overflow but I least it shows that they have similar width now.

Answer (score 7):

using css you can override the preferred width of all buttons like

```
.button {
    -fx-pref-width: 200px;
}
```

or create your own style class for certain button groups and add the style to the button like:
css:

```
.my-special-button {
    -fx-pref-height: 28px;
    -fx-pref-width: 200px;
}
```

and then set the style to your button with either
fxml:

```
styleClass="my-special-button"
```

or in java

```
myButton.getStyleClass().add("my-special-button");
```