# How equitably distribute node in VBox in JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, distribution, vbox

How can I distribute equitably several section in a VBox?
In other words, I have this FXML code:

```
<Tab text="SOO properties">
    <content>
        <VBox>
            <HBox>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name" />
                <TextField />
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Number of MobileEntity slots" />
                <TextField />
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="MobileEntity buffer size" />
                <TextField />
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Connections number" />
                <TextField />
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Peripherals number" />
                <TextField />
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </content>
</Tab>
```

That product this view:

[image]

How can I obtain something like that?

[image]

Comment: you can use javafx gridpane and voilla!http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html

Comment: Also have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754524/javafx-buttons-with-same-size#25754619

Comment: Thanks, it works fine!

Comment: please remove your answer from your question, create a new answer and accept it ... or ask that guy who gave you your answer to write an actual answer. The current state is ... confusing

Comment: Done. I have to wait 2 days to mark my answer as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to GoXr3Plus, GridPane works good for this case:

```
<Tab text="SOO properties">
    <GridPane prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="358.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
        <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Number of MobileEntity slots" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="MobileEntity buffer size" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Connections number" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Peripherals number" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        </children>
    </GridPane>
</Tab>
```

Produces this view:

[image]