# Is there a way to "autofit" elements on a page so they take up the entire canvas

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX, is there a way to "autofit" elements on a page so they take up the entire thing?

Currently, I'm trying to make the window have two buttons that together take up the entire canvas, but I am not sure how to do that, given that it is possible to stretch the window, etc. I've tried playing around with `Button.setPrefSize`, but the button size stays the same, it just shows you a window with two outsized buttons, the text of which is not visible.

What I currently have

[image: What I currently have]

What I want (but for any window size)

[image]

Comment: Currently I'm using Flowpane, but if there's a better way to do this, that's fine too.

Comment: `button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE)`.  Study: [tips for sizing and slinging nodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm#JFXLY133) and the other info on layout panes in that tutorial.

Comment: Edit the question to add additional info instead of writing comments.   Provide your code as a [mcve].

Comment: Related: [JavaFX buttons with same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754524/javafx-buttons-with-same-size)

Comment: Canvas means something else in JavaFX (research it), try to use accurate terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way (code here but also possible in Scene Builder and FXML):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApplication extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button button1 = new Button("Button1");
        HBox.setHgrow(button1, Priority.SOMETIMES);
        button1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button1.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        Button button2 = new Button("Button2");
        HBox.setHgrow(button2, Priority.SOMETIMES);
        button2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button2.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(button1, button2);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(hBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(hBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(hBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane rootContainer = new AnchorPane(hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootContainer, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```